# I have a dll that can't be put in the same directory of the exe that calls it. How can I configure visual studio to find it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

My msi installer project includes two different versions of a dll with the exact same name, targeting the usual root install folder. So when the installer runs on the client machine, only one of them gets installed.

I guess I have to tell the installer project to put the older dll in a different folder. The problem is, how do I tell the program to look in that specific folder for that specific dll? I'm using C# and VS2010.

Thanks,

Isaac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suffix the assemblies according to their version numbers and deploy them to the same directory that way. Otherwise, it will get really messy with updates.

If you really want, you can use this sort of an app.config file to relocate the assembly: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="MyAssembly2"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="307041694a995978"/>
            <codeBase version="1.0.1524.23149" href="FILE://C:/Myassemblies/MyAssembly2.dll"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There microsoft assemblies. Its the reportviewer 9 and 10 dlls to be specific. Will I get into trouble if I change their names? I will try your App.Config solution tomorrow.

Comment: i still didn't try the app.config file way though, can you tell me what the advantages are of doing it this way over just Assembly.loadfrom?

Comment: Obvious advantage is that you can redirect to another assembly at any other time without requiring an application recompile. Also this is generally regarded as a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just ended up manually loading the assemblies. As in using Assembly.LoadFrom(relative path string)

I tried suffixing them but it started complaining it didn't match the app.manifest file.

The assembly resolve event also didn't work, because the reportviewer control didn't fire assemblyresolve for all of the dlls. Maybe because it's in it's own appdomain.

Anyway, this seems to work for now.

-Isaac